# Embed ViewController in NavigationController when it is already presented - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Is it possible to embed a ViewController in a UINavigationController when it is already presented?

I know that to present a ViewController in a NavigationController you should initialise it before like this:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to present a VC:

```
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

and once it is presented to embed it inside a NavigationController.

Comment: i am wondering what the UI you wanna make looks like.

Comment: I'm presenting a ViewController using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning and it would be really hard to present a NavigationController, so that's why I was asking